# When wish is used to emulate a spell, what is the casting time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

When wish is used to emulate a spell of an allowed level that has a lenghty casting time, what is the casting time for the wish?

The same as wish or the same as the emulated spell?

Comment: [related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106389/can-the-wish-spell-overcome-the-post-casting-time-requirements-of-the-clone-spel)

Answer (score 23):

## Your casting time is 1 action

Wish only takes a casting of time 1 action to fulfill your Wish. In this case of emulating a spell with longer casting times, it bypasses that longer casting time because (PHB, 288). Emphasis is mine.:

> You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. **The spell simply takes effect**.

Using your 9th level slot as a Wish for a lower level spell basically allows you to get what you want NOW (ignoring any casting times that it would have cost) and without any material cost.

Comment: So, basically, for any character that can cast wish: upcasting a spell to 9th level slot makes it eschew the components **and** the longer casting time.

Comment: Correct, the spell simply takes effect.

Comment: Yep, so if you have nothing else to Wish for that day you can avoid expensive spell components and longer casting times (making an area Hallowed, Resurrecting a dead ally).