# How powerful is the Planar Binding spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The *Planar Binding* spell is the answer to the classic trope of dark mages summoning and binding demons to their service. But what is the extent of this spell’s capacities in 5e?

1. **What scope of orders can be given?**
   Can suicidal orders be given? Even further, could you order the being to repeatedly attack itself until death (the closest thing to suicide in 5e)?
   Can you order a bound creature to be a “willing” participant in a spell? Spells like *Plane Shift* and *True Polymorph* depend on the willingness of the target to avoid saves.
2. **Can truly any fey, celestial, fiend, or elemental be bound?**
   MToF added stats for demon princes and a lord of hell; could such fiends (assuming you could beat the resistances) be bound?
3. **Does a creature need to understand your orders to obey?**
   This might seem like a dumb question, but certain beings might have too low intelligence to understand language; what kind of orders can they be given?

Comment: Your third question seems a bit different from the rest, and already has an answer: "[When wish is used to emulate a spell, what is the casting time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106819)", I think it can safely be removed which would make your questions feel more like a single question

Comment: You’re right! Will do.

Comment: I think the question is too broad in its current state. Even the "first" question is actually a pack of three distinct questions. We have a separate question just for "how can I make a creature willing": [Can you make an unwilling creature willing? In other words, what defines “willing”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/)

Comment: I think the three questions are pretty distinct, and could probably each be asked separately (i.e. #2 and #3 could be edited out and asked separately, with this question focusing solely on #1). #1 itself is asking multiple different questions, with the "willing" part covered by the question enkryptor linked - so this question could focus just on the suicidal/self-attacking orders issue.

Comment: Your questions are good questions, but the question's very broad as-is, and it's very hard for a single answer to address all of them adequately - each of them is distinct enough to be its own separate Q&A. The answer to any one of the questions is not dependent on or closely related to the answers to the others, which seems like a good reason to ask them as separate posts (i.e. one post for the "suicidal orders"/"repeatedly attack itself" part of #1, one post for #2, one post for #3 (if it's not already covered by an existing Q&A)).